# ошибка при executeQuery()

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
while (true) {
            resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
            int count = 0;
            while (resultset.next()) {
                count = resultset.getInt(1);
            }

            if (count > curId) {
                System.out.println("UPDATE");
                String query1 = "SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE id = " + count;
                resultset = statement.executeQuery(query1);
                // проверка шаг 1 или 2
                // Дальше только при шаге 2
                int status = 100;
                String query2 = "INSERT INTO help (id, status) VALUES (" + count + ", " + status + ")";
                statement.executeUpdate(query2);
                curId = count;
            }

            String query3 = "SELECT * FROM help WHERE status = 400";
            testResultset = statement.executeQuery(query3);
            while (testResultset.next()) { // здесь возникает ошибка после удаления
                int id = testResultset.getInt(1);
                String query_delete = "DELETE FROM help WHERE id = " + id ;
                statement.executeUpdate(query_delete);
            }

            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
```

Цикл крутиться нормально, но после удаления одного элемента возникает ошибка

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, то resultset  и statement  нужно закрыть. либо держать второй statement и через него выполнить удаление

Comment: и еще у вас бесконечный циул. а точку выхода не вижу.

Comment: Он должен быть бесконечным)

Comment: ResultSet и Statement закрываются в finally блоке (все это в try) поэтому ошибки в этом быть не может

Comment: Как вариант можете из `testResultset` получить список нужных ИД и положить их в коллекцию, а во втором цикле использовать ее для удаления.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключается в том, как вы извлекаете данные. Каждый раз, когда вы вызываете executeQuery, вы получаете свежий ResultSet, но вы его не закрываете.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.
>
> По умолчанию одновременно может быть открыт только один объект
>   ResultSet для объекта Statement. Поэтому, если чтение одного объекта
>   ResultSet чередуется с чтением другого, каждый из них должен быть
>   сгенерирован различными объектами Statement. Все методы выполнения в
>   интерфейсе Statement неявно закрывают текущий объект ResultSet, если
>   существует открытый.

Если коротко, то у вас есть несколько ResultSet, относящихся к тому же самому объекту Statement одновременно. И вы его не закрываете.

Вы можете создать другой Statement  объект для удаления записи  в БД. либо же закрыть RS